# How can i have T4 Code Generator in VS 2008?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, t4

I have a project in .Net Framework 3.5 and i shouldn't improve it to 4 or 4.5 .Net Framework , but i'd like to have a code generator like .Net Framework 4.5 What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Visual Studio 2008 [already has T4 included](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx).

> Now, go into Visual Studio and make a Console App (or any app) and add
>   a Text File, but name it something with a .tt extension.